# Ms access. Join expression not supported

Tags: sql, ms-access

```
Select UUID, COUNT(FosterID)
FROM tblUsers
Left JOIN tblAnimals On (UUID=FosterID)
Group By UUID
```

I want to get all users and the number of animals they are fostering those who are not have 0

Comment: Auto correct changed it was a prefix

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try a full qualified name like

```
Select tblUsers.UUID, COUNT(tblAnimals.FosterID)
FROM tblUsers
Left JOIN tblAnimals On (tblUsers.UUID=tblAnimals.FosterID)
Group By tblUsers.UUID
```